# What are some ways to improve on a voltage divider without a voltage regulator IC?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

We all know the basic voltage divider. It looks something like this. Two identical resistors and the voltage in the middle.

[image]

I am, however, running into uses where this voltage divider is inadequately accurate. For context, I am using this voltage divider to create a bias voltage for several Op-Amps forming a bridge-tied load as well as a gain amplifier.

Firstly, I have other voltage sources that are coming from the other side of the voltage divider. Many of these voltages are high frequency signals from Op-Amps or an ultrasonic receiver. I don't know how relevant this will be but I'm just putting this out there in case it is.

Secondly, I have significant loads on the other sides. The math I did suggests the smaller the resistors, the more accurate the voltage will remain. However, I can only set the resistors to be low to an extent before they catch fire.

[image]

The math. Any suggestions are welcome, even uses that don't entirely fit my use case since I'm (and I'm sure a lot of others) are curious to other use cases in general. I'd like to avoid voltage regulator ICs if possible since I don't have any half-decent ones available to me.

Comment: You improve a voltage divider (in your use case) by using some sort of voltage regulator.

Comment: `Two identical resistors and the voltage in the middle.` - hardly ever true.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm trying to do this without an IC. Thanks for the edit reminder and your suggestion.

Comment: @Andyaka Why is that? I'm assuming for more advanced uses there would be more components, but why is that hardly ever true for a simple divider?

Comment: The resistors need not be equal and usually arent - it depends entirely on your application. Equal resistors are only required  when division ratio is 1:2 at no load. Accuracy without active components is calculable as you know. There is no sensible passive way to improve it. Adding an active device (emitter follower, shunt regulator, series regulator ....will improve the result to whatever extent you design it to.

Comment: One improvement you can make is to add capacitors across the resistors to lower the AC impedance. Doesn't do anything to help with the problems of low available current and susceptibility of the divider to be unbalanced due to unequal loading above and below the center point, but it helps with noise.
When you say 'without using an IC' does that allow for using transistors?

Comment: Re, "I'm trying to do this without an IC." Trying to do _what?_ There's no place in your question where you say what you actually are trying to accomplish. You say you want an "improved" voltage divider, but improved for what purpose? What are you hoping to do with it?

Comment: Edited based off @GodJihyo and Solomon Slow's suggestions.

Comment: @HFOrangefish There is not a single **number** in the question. At least inform what are the accuracy requirements and current needs.

Comment: If you don't have any half-decent regulators available, what about bad old LM317? Still a lot better for most purposes than a crude voltage divider.

Comment: @HFOrangefish - Hi, Since you already know that using a voltage divider to provide a supply rail has *significant* problems (e.g. depending on your "output" voltage requirements, what compromises you can make e.g. wasted power in the voltage divider resistors etc.) this previous Q&A probably just says what you already know. But for future readers who may not yet understand, I'll link to this explanation: "[When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/106718/101852)"

Comment: **before they catch fire**  I believe the op-amps are personally proud of this.  Op-amps are high impedance, so they should have very little impact on a voltage divider.  You need to show us a circuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one Channel on one op amp.

Not a voltage regulator but it does use an "IC" so I don't know where that falls into your requirements.

You can add capacitors in parallel with the resistors to further stabilize the voltage divider that gets reproduced on the op amp output.  You can also use a zener in the voltage divider to further stabilize and then use the op amp to make that voltage "stiffer" as we used to say.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*...without an integrated circuit*

@GTElectronics has given a fine answer that is often used (but it involves an integrated circuit).

Another, less ideal solution involves replacing the lower (grounded) resistor with a zener diode, or avalanche diode. However, be aware that these come in standard voltages, so you cannot use them for an arbitrary output voltage. The increments of voltage for standard diodes are close-enough together that you can [find one suitable for your application](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352448/understanding-zener-diode-datasheet).

Be aware that these diodes cannot handle infinite power. They are rated in terms of watts (or milliwatts). Some are 250 mW, others 500 mW. For the circuit shown, if the 9V battery starts at +10V, and runs-down to 7V, output voltage remains fairly constant: it only changes from +5.07V to +5.04V... a far smaller range than a 2-resistor voltage divider can do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjJTPo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>